# How to round decimals to integers while normalizing in a nested dictionary so that it adds up to a whole number in python

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, rounding, normalization

I have a nested dictionary which I have normalized. I would like to round the result so that it adds up to 100 at the end. However, when I do rounding it adds up to 101 and I want to apply a simple trick so that it can always add up to 100.

My nested dictionary is as :

```
nest_dict={'D': {'A': '0.20','B': '0.27','C': '0.20','D': '0.10','E': '0.06','F': '0.08','G': '0.02'}}
```

I have normalized my nest_dict as:

```
def normalize(d, target=1.0):
    raw = sum(float(number) for number in d.values())
    factor = (target/raw if raw else 0)
    return {key: float(value)*factor*100 for key, value in d.items()}
normalized_dict={key: normalize(dct) for key, dct in nest_dict.items()}
```

which gives me the result as:

```
{'D': {'A': 21.50537634408602,'B': 29.03225806451613,'C': 21.50537634408602,'D': 10.75268817204301,'E': 6.451612903225806,'F': 8.602150537634408, 'G': 2.150537634408602}}
```

However, I would like to get the numbers as integers which add up to 100. When I use **round** it gives me 101 or when I use **math.ceil** it also doesn't give me 100.
Any suggestion on how to get the values as integers which would add up to 100 such as

```
{'D': {'A': 22,'B': 29,'C': 22,'D': 11,'E': 6,'F': 8, 'G': 2}}
```

Even if there is a solution by changing other value of a key, I am still okay with other options as long as it adds up to 100.
Thanks

Comment: I've had good luck using the [iteround](https://pypi.org/project/iteround/) package for this.

Comment: @NickODell thanks for your suggestion. If I am not mistaken, this package does not support python 3.7 version and I am using 3.7 version of python.

Comment: What do you mean by that? I tried it just now on Python 3.7, and it seems like it works fine. Terminal output: https://pastebin.com/KnKNcS7y

Comment: When I try to install it I have an error 'ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement iterround (from versions: none)'. That was the reason. Thanks